# No keyword with name 'Get Cell Data' found' in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to read excel data from robot framework. I installed excel library through command

```
pip install robotframework-excel library
```

Still I get this error:

> No keyword with name 'Get Cell Data' found.

Code: Settings Library ExcelLibrary Variables

Test Cases demo Test: Open Excel Z:\hello.xls

Get Cell Data       status:     A1

Status is my sheet name:
A1 is the cell name

I tried this option with different indentation. But no luck. I get this error for many keywords in excel. I would like to know what am missing here.

Comment: can u attach with the erorr message ?

Comment: Can you provide a complete example of your robot code. This should include all the header sections.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might confused with example in [Documentation](http://navinet.github.io/robotframework-excellibrary/ExcelLibrary-KeywordDocumentation.html).
Please find below code and this is the correct keyword.

```
${data}         Read Cell Data By Name    Sheet1    A1
```

If you want use the column and row to return the data from that cell.

```
${data}    Read Cell Data By Coordinates  Sheet1    2  3
```

Comment: @JayanthiB if the below 2 answer was correct please help choose one for the accept answer. thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no `Get Cell Data` in the library.

Check the list of available keywords in [the documentation](https://zero-88.github.io/robotframework-excel/docs/ExcelRobot.html).

The keyword you are looking for is probably `Read Cell Data`

Comment: Thank you. The documentation was helpful. I was looking for Read Cell Data By Name